# Prepositional phrase after the verb “was"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

What is the role of the prepositional phrase **with his friend** in the sentence below:

> He was **with his friend** when I saw him today.

Does it function as an **adverbial** or **complement**?

Answer (score 3):

> *He was with his friend when I saw him today.*

The preposition phrase "with his friend" is a complement of "be".

It can't be an adjunct (adverbial) since it is obligatory, and such items are always complements: they are needed to complete the verb phrase.

Adjuncts can occur in copular clauses though; compare:

> *He was with his friend at that time.*

Comment: and what about this sentence : She has been working with her sister for two years. is the preposition WITH a prepositional verb or a  complement??

Comment: @OsamaFeras  The PP "with her sister" is an optional item, and hence is an adjunct (adverbial) modifying "working".

Comment: so is it a prepositional verb??

Comment: @OsamaFeras I don't follow you. "With" is a preposition, not a verb.

Comment: @OsamaFeras If you're asking whether "work with" is a phrasal verb, the answer is no. "work" is a verb by itself, and "with" is an ordinary preposition that introduces the propositional phrase "with her sister", which functions as an adverb that modifies the verb "work". If you tried to reword it as "She has been working her sister with", that would be ungrammatical.

Comment: no, the prepositional verbs are certain verbs followed by certain adjectives, such as look at

Comment: @OsamaFeras That's nonsense. In "look at", "look"  is not a prepositional verb. And in any case "at" is not an adjective, but a preposition. Please stop posting rubbish on this website.

Comment: oh. i wanted to write prepositions instead of adjectives

Comment: i'm not posting rubbish. It was very rude of you to write that. and on most English grammar websites , theses verb-preposition pairs are called prepositional verbs.

Comment: @OsamaFeras You have been given an answer to your question. Now I suggest you digest what you've been told. Note that your original question was not about prepositional verbs, but about PPs after the verb "was". If you want to know about prepositional verbs, then ask a new question on that particular topic. Okay?

Answer (score 1):

It is a subject complement referring to "he"

Comment: Thanks. are there certain rules governing the uses and placements of preposition??. for example the prepositional phrase with can be a subject complement , an object complement , and an adverbial.